# Can you add even listener and overwrite the behavior to browsers search text feature in javascript?

Tags: javascript, search, browser, find, text-search

I'm looking for a way to overwrite the ctrl + F text search functionality in browsers. Is there way to overwrite the hehavior into the initiation/searching/next/prev hooks?

Comment: yes, you can listen for and "hijack" ctrl+f

Comment: Is there a way to high jack the actual search and not just the ctrl + f hotkey?

Comment: and if I say yes, will you change the goal posts again?

Comment: @JaromandaX what goal posts?